# Populating custom class properties using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

First of all , I'm new to reflection . I've created class :

```
using System.Reflection;

 public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

}
```

Now I'm trying to develop a method that will populate all the properties using some business logic (if null then empty string etc) via reflection, and returning a list of `EmployeeInfo`. I thought it should look something like this :

```
public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)
    {

        var listEmployeeInfo = new List<Models.EmployeeInfo>();
        var propertyNames = new List<string>() {"EmployeeName","Position","Office","IsPublic"};

        foreach (SPListItem item in splic)
        {
            var employeeInfo = new Models.EmployeeInfo();


            foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
            {
                string newData = "";
                if (item[propertyName] != null)
                {
                    newData = item[propertyName].ToString();
                }
                employeeInfo.GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(employeeInfo, newData, null);

            }
            listEmployeeInfo.Add(employeeInfo);
        }

        return listEmployeeInfo;


    }
```

But I can't call `GetProperty` or `SetValue` extension methods at this line :

```
employeeInfo.GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(employeeInfo, newData, null);
```

Error Message says that my `Models.EmployeeInfo` class doesn't contain definition for `GetProperty` and no extension method `GetProperty` .
What is missing ?
Thank you .

Comment: I asked the same question on code review site. I got some very good review comments to do this. You can check the question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102289/setting-the-value-of-properties-via-reflection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetProperty is a method on the Type class.

```
employeeInfo.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(employeeInfo, newData, null);
```

Comment: Thank you Andy , I've tried this one, but I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: You need to debug your code. Put a break point in, and for each step think about what you think should happen, then watch what actually happens. I suspect that GetProperty will be returning a null for some reason, but that's what you'll find out with the debugging.

Comment: Found the bug.Thank you!